# Jquery Datatables IE 10 fnAddData slow performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, datatables

Really strange: I was trying to figure out why when I added 200 rows with `fnAddData` it took about 4.4 seconds, but when I added data using just jquery `append()` function it took about 100 milliseconds.

What exactly is slowing fnAddData down?

Environment: IE 10, datatables 1.9.4

Comment: You're surprised that parsing, formatting and sorting those rows before adding them to the DOM takes longer?

Comment: But I have all these things turned off.

Comment: fnAddData takes two parameters; the second (redraw) is optional and set to true by default.  Try setting it to false; then after adding all your data, call fnDraw to redraw the table.